# Strange I2C behavior: sometime it works, some time it doesn't

Tags: arduino, communication, ethernet, i2c, wire

I am using [Arduino Ethernet with PoE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet) and [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) boards. In recent days I implemented a working I2C bus by using the [`Wire`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire) library and all it seemed almost to work: the two boards was communicating correctly, except in some cases.

Until yesterday I2C bus was working, now it doesn't. I didn't changed the physical location of any wire or sketch code: *I just started the PC in order to give power to boards*, and the communication over the I2C bus just stop working. Then, after a bit and some "reset" / "sketch re-upload" (note: I didn't changed any sketch code), it started to work again.

It is not the first time that this situation happens, and I am in trouble to catch the exact problem.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could be anything from physical wiring to software problems to EM problems.  This can be fairly difficult to pin down.  I'd start by using an oscilloscope to look at the I2C bus and see what the signals look like

Comment: How was it working before without power from the PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it's right on the margin of working; all sorts of tiny effects like EM noise from the computer, capacitance from the human body, and temperature are pushing it from "working" to "not working".

The general solution is to slow down the I2C or shield it more thoroughly.

Comment: Where can I know more about possible common EM noises for Arduino boards? For example, if I physically put my Arduino boards in a waterproof package and in the pouring rain, will those Arduino boards have some EM noises?

Comment: Not sure what rain has to do with it - the usual source is _other electrical equipment_. Switches, fluorescent tubes, power tools, and mobile phones are usual suspects.

Comment: I mentioned "rain" because I believe that even the climate surrounding (in this case, as an example, in particular environmental conditions like "pouring rain") can create EM noises. It is for that I asked: "Where can I know more about possible common EM noises for Arduino boards?".

Comment: In other words: How strong are the Arduino boards (in this case, relating to tolerating EM noises)?

Comment: I just posted a new question: [How strong are the Arduino boards?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66787/how-strong-are-the-arduino-boards)

Comment: Rain can apparently be an issue for aircraft: http://www.emcuk.co.uk/awareness/Pages/InterferenceExamples/AviationAerospace.htm although I don't think it's an issue for electronics that's grounded.

Comment: Really the only way to prove that something is EM-resistant is to either (1) test it or (2) find evidence that someone else has tested it; this should be related to the CE certification for the board, but that information does not appear to be readily available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you think I2C is not working, convert the I2C SCL and data-SDA lines as GPIO and bring the bus into a known state by sending a sequence through bus as given. The procedure is as follows:

1. Master tries to assert a Logic 1 on the SDA line
2. Master still sees a Logic 0 and then generates a clock pulse on SCL (1-0-1 transition)
3. Master examines SDA. If SDA = 0, go to Step 2; if SDA = 1, go to Step 4
4. Generate a STOP

Answer (score 0):

I2C using pull-up resistors can be finicky.  Try reducing the pull-up values to clean up the signal.  Or better yet (really much better) add an active terminator like the LTC4311 to the bus.

Comment: Eh, an active termination for I2C? Not sure I'd recommend that off the bat when we don't even know what the signals look like. I find it funny LT put a 15.8k as the pullup in their diagram. Why such a weak pullup? Of course the LT part looks better...