# How strong are the Arduino boards relating to interference robustness?

Tags: arduino, noise, board, environmental-sealing

In my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66779/strange-i2c-behavior-sometime-it-works-some-time-it-doesnt) the problem was related to EM noises with the Arduino boards, then I asked myself: *How strong are the Arduino boards relating to interference robustness?*

For example, if I physically put my Arduino boards in a waterproof package and in the pouring rain, will those Arduino boards have some EM noises? Can I use Arduino boards in that environmental condition (outdoor, pouring rain, etc) and make those to still work *reliably*?

Comment: Suggestion: This question isn't specifically about Arduino boards... The question is more generic to electronic circuit boards, perhaps boards with microcontrollers. You might want to edit your question to only mention the Arduino as a point in example, rather than the crux of the question.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh - The question is *intentionally* / *exactly* related to the usage of Arduino boards and it is not closed for "more generic to electronic circuit boards, perhaps boards with microcontrollers" answers. Arduino matters are the crux of the question.

Comment: I don't think the question is that bad, although it should be clearer that it's asking about EM immunity rather than some other kind of strength.

Comment: I reopened it, though I think there's still room for improvement. I also think that rain (if it's waterproof sealed) doesn't create interference, maybe just troubles in case of wireless communication.

Comment: @clabacchio - *BTW* For me, comments (like those that was present for this question) should be deleted, but *not* at all: at least, those comments, should be still available...

Comment: They are still available, but just for mods who can undelete them. Is there something that you would like to be visible?

Comment: @angelatlarge - Think of the rain, so abundant, that completely surrounds the waterproof package that contains the Arduino boards: what happens at that point relating to interferences? Even if the Arduino boards are placed in a reliable container, those were effectively underwater, and the EM Field (environmental conditions) has changed.

Comment: @clabacchio - It would be. It is for the downvoting of the question, since comments have strongly influenced opinions about this question.

Comment: Do you want to know about how rain affects the Arduino in particular, or about how EMI (Electromagnetic Interference) affects it in general? Rain is not a particularly problematic cause of EMI as far as I know. It might be a good exercise to read up a bit on EMI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference).

Comment: @user502052 EMI and Rain are not related, someone may have had a miscommunication with you.

Comment: And to be very clear, @user502052, asking a good question is your job, because you are the one needing help.

Comment: @Kortuk - You are right...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding the OP, then answer is a "no", unless it is raining energized transformers.  Rain (the kind made of water droplets) does not generate EM.

Comment: +1 for an appropriate answer :-) Oh, you forgot about [radioactive rain](https://www.baycitizen.org/news/japan-disaster/radioactive-rain-falling-us/).

Comment: So, the EM generated by the rain (the kind, so abundant, that completely surrounds the waterproof package that contains the Arduino boards making it to be effectively underwater) is so *weak* that it insignificantly influences the Arduino hardware?

Comment: Unless there's some physical phenomenon I'm not aware of, rainwater can affect propagation of EM waves (especially microwaves), but generate EM radiation? Seriously?

Comment: http://www.emcuk.co.uk/awareness/Pages/InterferenceExamples/AviationAerospace.htm - apparently it can tribocharge. Obviously it also conducts away charge, so this is only an issue for aircraft.

Comment: @user502052 the point here is clear, "Rain (the kind made of water droplets) does not generate EM."

Comment: @Kortuk - In fact, I am referring to "rain (the kind, so abundant, that completely surrounds the waterproof package that contains the Arduino boards making it to be effectively underwater)"...

Comment: @user502052 and we are trying to say, water, the kind that falls from the sky in normal conditions and you can drink, does not cause any Electromagnetic interference. Do you have a link to where someone told you otherwise?